# find precent of unpainted canvas (elipse art question)

Tags: java

I am trying to solve [this question](https://csacademy.com/ieeextreme-practice/task/ellipse-art/statement/). I wrote a solution, my solution is very close but not correct, I added my code below:

**My approach**

For each point (that is either randomly chosen or in the grid), you would test to see if it was within an ellipse. If the sum of the distance between the point and each foci is less than the radius, it is within the ellipse. Dividing the number of points that are not in any ellipse by the total number of points tested gives you an estimate of the proportion of the canvas that is unpainted. Increasing the number of points tested improves the accuracy of this estimate, and it is not difficult to meet the accuracy requirements of this problem

> Here is the question

[image]

[image]

> here my code

```
public class q1 {

    class Elipse {
        public double x1;
        public double x2;
        public double y1;
        public double y2;
        public double r;            
    }
    public static double dist(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
        double mid1 = x2 - x1, mid2 = y2 - y1;
        return Math.sqrt((mid1 * mid1) + (mid2 * mid2));
    }
   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = Integer.valueOf(input.nextLine());
        int inPoints = 0;
        double[] results=new double[t];
        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
            int n = Integer.valueOf(input.nextLine());
            Elipse[] elipses = new Elipse[n];
            for (int p = 0; p < n; p++) {
                String[] numbers = input.nextLine().split(" ");
                Elipse e = new q1().new Elipse();
                e.x1 = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]);
                e.x2 = Integer.parseInt(numbers[1]);
                e.y1 = Integer.parseInt(numbers[2]);
                e.y2 = Integer.parseInt(numbers[3]);
                e.r = Integer.parseInt(numbers[4]);
                elipses[p] = e;
            }

            int lim=50;
            double buffer=1;
            for (double j = -(lim)+0.5; j < lim; j+=buffer) {
                for (double k = -(lim)+0.5; k < lim; k+=buffer) {
                    for (Elipse e : elipses) {
                        double dist=dist(e.x1,e.y1,j,k)+dist(e.x2,e.y2,j,k);
                        if (dist<e.r){
                            inPoints++;
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                }               
            }   
            double size=(lim*2)*(lim*2);
            double out=size-inPoints;
            results[i]=(double)out/size;
            results[i]*=100;
            inPoints=0;

        }

        for (double d : results) {
            System.out.println(d+"%");
        }
    }
}
```

for the input:

```
3
1
-40 0 40 0 100
1
10 50 90 50 100
2
15 -20 15 20 50
-10 10 30 30 100
```

output should be:

```
53%
88%
41%
```

but my output is:

```
49.59%
88.99000000000001%
42.1%
```